# Rotronic Temp/Humidity probe locks into a "no communication" state with minimalmodbus and python

Tags: python, modbus, minimalmodbus

**EDIT**:
For whatever reason, this entire problem was solved (for now) with a finally statement that only contains time.sleep(1). It doesn't make any sense why that would work in my program, but it does. Thanks user Brits for the recommendation.

I am developing a sensor testing software using Python and the minimalmodbus package. I have gotten five other sensors to work with minimalmodbus with no issue. I'm having issues with this sensor by Rotronic (with modbus attachment): https://www.rotronic.com/en-us/rms-hcd-s.html.
Here is the manual: https://service.rotronic.com/manual/?_ga=2.154508728.1456734610.1628031858-1559765634.1628031858.
Navigation: Hardware Overview > Sensors and Probes > HCD-Sx > MODBUS

It's a little difficult to explain the issue, but I'll do my best.
I can successfully poll from the device several times without any issue. Periodically I will get a "No communication error" that looks like this with minimalmodbus debugging turned on:

```
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 9 bytes back): '÷\x04y\x1a\x00\x02]Æ' (F7 04 79 1A 00 02 5D C6)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM4
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 1000.00 ms, minimum silent period: 2.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '÷\x04\x04î$ÅA\x8bÈ' (F7 04 04 EE 24 C5 41 8B C8) (9 bytes), roundtrip time: 31.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 50.0 ms.

24.64303207397461
#temp from previous request

MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 9 bytes back): '÷\x04y\x1a\x00\x02]Æ' (F7 04 79 1A 00 02 5D C6)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM4
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 1016.00 ms, minimum silent period: 2.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '' () (0 bytes), roundtrip time: 63.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 50.0 ms.

No communication with the instrument (no answer)
# a '' was returned

MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 9 bytes back): '÷\x04y\x1a\x00\x02]Æ' (F7 04 79 1A 00 02 5D C6)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM4
MinimalModbus debug mode. Sleeping 2.01 ms before sending. Minimum silent period: 2.01 ms, time since read: 0.00 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '÷\x04\x04i\x0cÅA#t' (F7 04 04 69 0C C5 41 23 74) (9 bytes), roundtrip time: 0.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 50.0 ms.

24.631059646606445
#temp again
```

Then, periodically I will get two checksum errors in a row:

```
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 9 bytes back): '÷\x04y\x1a\x00\x02]Æ' (F7 04 79 1A 00 02 5D C6)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM4
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 1016.00 ms, minimum silent period: 2.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '÷\x04\x04\x9f&ÅA1' (F7 04 04 9F 26 C5 41 31) (8 bytes), roundtrip time: 62.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 50.0 ms.

Checksum error in rtu mode: 'A1' instead of '\x0f±' . The response is: '÷\x04\x04\x9f&ÅA1' (plain response: '÷\x04\x04\x9f&ÅA1')
# checksum error

MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 9 bytes back): '÷\x04y\x1a\x00\x02]Æ' (F7 04 79 1A 00 02 5D C6)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM4
MinimalModbus debug mode. Sleeping 2.01 ms before sending. Minimum silent period: 2.01 ms, time since read: 0.00 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '4÷\x04\x04\x9f&ÅA1' (34 F7 04 04 9F 26 C5 41 31) (9 bytes), roundtrip time: 31.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 50.0 ms.

Checksum error in rtu mode: 'A1' instead of 'ai' . The response is: '4÷\x04\x04\x9f&ÅA1' (plain response: '4÷\x04\x04\x9f&ÅA1')
# checksum error again

MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 9 bytes back): '÷\x04y\x1a\x00\x02]Æ' (F7 04 79 1A 00 02 5D C6)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM4
MinimalModbus debug mode. Sleeping 2.01 ms before sending. Minimum silent period: 2.01 ms, time since read: 0.00 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '÷\x04\x04\x9f&ÅA14' (F7 04 04 9F 26 C5 41 31 34) (9 bytes), roundtrip time: 31.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 50.0 ms.

24.643857955932617
#back to normal
```

These errors don't break anything, it's easy to fix with exception statements, but the real issue is when the device just stops responding entirely. I wrote a small script specifically for showing this issue:

```
def test():
    count = 0
    ins = mm.Instrument('COM4', 247, debug=True)
    while True:
        try:
            temp = ins.read_float(31002, functioncode=4, number_of_registers=2, byteorder=1)
            print(temp)
            time.sleep(1)
            count = 0
        except mm.NoResponseError as e:
            print(e)
            count += 1
            if count > 3:
                print(mm._get_diagnostic_string())
                break
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

test()
```

This script can run for anywhere from 1 minute to maybe 6 minutes before the sensor just stops responding. Here is the debug output and the diagnosis script:

```
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 9 bytes back): '÷\x04y\x1a\x00\x02]Æ' (F7 04 79 1A 00 02 5D C6)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM4
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 1015.00 ms, minimum silent period: 2.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '÷\x04\x04î$ÅA\x8bÈ' (F7 04 04 EE 24 C5 41 8B C8) (9 bytes), roundtrip time: 16.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 50.0 ms.

24.64303207397461
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 9 bytes back): '÷\x04y\x1a\x00\x02]Æ' (F7 04 79 1A 00 02 5D C6)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM4
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 1015.00 ms, minimum silent period: 2.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '÷' (F7) (1 bytes), roundtrip time: 63.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 50.0 ms.

Too short Modbus RTU response (minimum length 4 bytes). Response: '÷'
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 9 bytes back): '÷\x04y\x1a\x00\x02]Æ' (F7 04 79 1A 00 02 5D C6)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM4
MinimalModbus debug mode. Sleeping 2.01 ms before sending. Minimum silent period: 2.01 ms, time since read: 0.00 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '\x04\x04Ù*ÅAä\x7f÷' (04 04 D9 2A C5 41 E4 7F F7) (9 bytes), roundtrip time: 0.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 50.0 ms.

Checksum error in rtu mode: '\x7f÷' instead of 'j©' . The response is: '\x04\x04Ù*ÅAä\x7f÷' (plain response: '\x04\x04Ù*ÅAä\x7f÷')
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 9 bytes back): '÷\x04y\x1a\x00\x02]Æ' (F7 04 79 1A 00 02 5D C6)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM4
MinimalModbus debug mode. Sleeping 2.01 ms before sending. Minimum silent period: 2.01 ms, time since read: 0.00 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '\x04Ù*ÅAä\x7f÷\x04' (04 D9 2A C5 41 E4 7F F7 04) (9 bytes), roundtrip time: 0.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 50.0 ms.

Checksum error in rtu mode: '÷\x04' instead of '27' . The response is: '\x04Ù*ÅAä\x7f÷\x04' (plain response: '\x04Ù*ÅAä\x7f÷\x04')
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 9 bytes back): '÷\x04y\x1a\x00\x02]Æ' (F7 04 79 1A 00 02 5D C6)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM4
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 15.00 ms, minimum silent period: 2.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: 'ÅAä\x7f' (C5 41 E4 7F) (4 bytes), roundtrip time: 63.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 50.0 ms.

Checksum error in rtu mode: 'ä\x7f' instead of '\x92Ð' . The response is: 'ÅAä\x7f' (plain response: 'ÅAä\x7f')
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 9 bytes back): '÷\x04y\x1a\x00\x02]Æ' (F7 04 79 1A 00 02 5D C6)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM4
MinimalModbus debug mode. Sleeping 2.01 ms before sending. Minimum silent period: 2.01 ms, time since read: 0.00 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '' () (0 bytes), roundtrip time: 62.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 50.0 ms.

No communication with the instrument (no answer)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 9 bytes back): '÷\x04y\x1a\x00\x02]Æ' (F7 04 79 1A 00 02 5D C6)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM4
MinimalModbus debug mode. Sleeping 2.01 ms before sending. Minimum silent period: 2.01 ms, time since read: 0.00 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '' () (0 bytes), roundtrip time: 62.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 50.0 ms.

No communication with the instrument (no answer)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 9 bytes back): '÷\x04y\x1a\x00\x02]Æ' (F7 04 79 1A 00 02 5D C6)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM4
MinimalModbus debug mode. Sleeping 2.01 ms before sending. Minimum silent period: 2.01 ms, time since read: 0.00 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '' () (0 bytes), roundtrip time: 62.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 50.0 ms.

No communication with the instrument (no answer)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 9 bytes back): '÷\x04y\x1a\x00\x02]Æ' (F7 04 79 1A 00 02 5D C6)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM4
MinimalModbus debug mode. Sleeping 2.01 ms before sending. Minimum silent period: 2.01 ms, time since read: 0.00 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '' () (0 bytes), roundtrip time: 62.0 ms. Timeout for reading: 50.0 ms.

No communication with the instrument (no answer)

## Diagnostic output from minimalmodbus ##

Minimalmodbus version: 1.0.2
Minimalmodbus status: Production
File name (with relative path): c:\Users\natalieb\Desktop\Python\Repositories\environmental_chamber_ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\minimalmodbus.py
Full file path: c:\Users\natalieb\Desktop\Python\Repositories\environmental_chamber_ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\minimalmodbus.py

pySerial version: 3.5
pySerial full file path: c:\Users\natalieb\Desktop\Python\Repositories\environmental_chamber_ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\serial\__init__.py

Platform: win32
Filesystem encoding: 'utf-8'
Byteorder: little
Python version: 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
Python version info: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=9, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
Python flags: sys.flags(debug=0, inspect=0, interactive=0, optimize=0, dont_write_bytecode=0, no_user_site=0, no_site=0, ignore_environment=0, verbose=0, bytes_warning=0, quiet=0, hash_randomization=1, isolated=0, dev_mode=False, utf8_mode=0)
Python argv: ['c:\\Users\\natalieb\\Desktop\\Python\\Repositories\\environmental_chamber_ui\\test scripts\\minimalmodbus_test.py']
Python prefix: 'c:\\Users\\natalieb\\Desktop\\Python\\Repositories\\environmental_chamber_ui\\.venv'
Python exec prefix: 'c:\\Users\\natalieb\\Desktop\\Python\\Repositories\\environmental_chamber_ui\\.venv'
Python executable: 'c:\\Users\\natalieb\\Desktop\\Python\\Repositories\\environmental_chamber_ui\\.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe'
Long info: (none)
Float repr style: 'short'

Variable __name__: minimalmodbus
Current directory: C:\Users\natalieb\Desktop\Python\Repositories\environmental_chamber_ui

Python path:
c:\Users\natalieb\Desktop\Python\Repositories\environmental_chamber_ui\test scripts
C:\Users\natalieb\Desktop\Python\Repositories\sensor_testing\tools
C:\Users\natalieb\Desktop\Python\Repositories\environmental_chamber_ui
C:\Users\natalieb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip
C:\Users\natalieb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs
C:\Users\natalieb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
C:\Users\natalieb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
c:\Users\natalieb\Desktop\Python\Repositories\environmental_chamber_ui\.venv
c:\Users\natalieb\Desktop\Python\Repositories\environmental_chamber_ui\.venv\lib\site-packages
c:\Users\natalieb\Desktop\Python\Repositories\environmental_chamber_ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\win32
c:\Users\natalieb\Desktop\Python\Repositories\environmental_chamber_ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
c:\Users\natalieb\Desktop\Python\Repositories\environmental_chamber_ui\.venv\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin

## End of diagnostic output ##
```

The no response error will repeat indefinitely unless the loop is broken. The sensor goes into a locked state where it's only possible to re-connect with it if it is unplugged and plugged back in. It won't even communicate with another program (ModbusReader by KurySoft) when the sensor is in this locked state. I haven't run into any issues with this sensor using just ModbusReader, so it leads me to believe it is an incompatibility with minimalmodbus that I don't have enough knowledge to understand.

The "Too short Modbus Response" error doesn't always lead to the sensor lock state and it doesn't always proceed it. Sometimes no other error will proceed the "no communication" error. It just stops communicating with no warning.

I am reaching out to the developers of the sensor as well, but they aren't too interested in understanding the issue. I don't think anything I send should cause a sensor to lock up, so I want to declare this a sensor issue and send it back, but I can't replicate the issue with another program.

If there's a way I can edit my code or the minimalmodbus library to fix this issue, I'd love the help. Thank you.

Comment: My first thought would be a firmware issue on the device - is it running [release 1.5](https://www.rotronic.com/en-us/productattachments/index/download?id=1991)? (the v1.4 release notes mention "RS485 Network communication handling improved" - not really much detail but possible this relates to the issue you are seeing if you unit is on a previous version). It may also be worth adding a small delay after a failed read (currently you retry immediately; I have seen devices lock up when polled too quickly).

Comment: Could it be a firmware issue even if it's working with another program?

This sensor's certificate says it's version 1.5.

The communication error happens no matter how much time is between each poll. Nor does it matter what the timeout limit is. This little script was just written to catch the issue, but I should've moved the time.sleep() at the end anyway.
I originally caught the issue while running my program, which has a 2-3 second delay before polling from it again. However, polling from it more frequently does seem to cause it to fail sooner.

Comment: Different programs will have subtle differences (timing etc) that could trigger a bug (always worth ensuring you have the latest firmware). The fact that the unit locks completely (you need to power cycle it) points towards an issue on the device itself (with well written firmware is it should not lock up whatever you send it). I'm assuming that you are polling the unit at the same frequency with ModbusReader?

Comment: Both programs are polling at 1000 ms. And ModbusReader is actually polling three different registers: temp, humidity, and the serial number.
 I agree that the sensor shouldn't lock up at all.
I'm more confused now though, because I ran a test over night with the time.sleep(1) in a "finally" statement, to double check it wasn't a sleep issue, but it was still running when I got back in this morning.
I'm going to add that same finally statement to my program and see what happens. It's confusing though, bc when I first discovered the issue, it would only poll every 2-3 seconds.

Comment: I'm going to keep messing with it, and update this post if the time.sleep thing works with my program.
Thank you for your help, it's going to be a little embarrassing if this works, but at least it will work haha

Comment: my guess is that this device cannot handle being polled multiple times with no gap. With your existing code this happened when an error occurred (which will happen from time to time, RS485 comms are not perfect).

Comment: I understand why it would have an issue with the sample code I gave. However, I first discovered the issue in the program I am writing where the sensor has to wait for it's turn in the queue before it gets polled again, error or not. So when I discovered the issue, it wasn't being polled too quickly, Maybe it's something to do with switching to the other sensors on the COM too quickly, or something else I don't understand. Either way, the sleep statement helps my program as well, so thank you.

Comment: Because these units are on an RS485 bus they receive all transmissions; code on each device filters out commands not directed at them (using Slave ID).  This means that it can be possible to cause a device to crash without directing any commands at it (I have seen this happen with an Arduino where frequently polling other devices on the bus lead to a crash; resolved by increasing inter query delay). Should not really happen with well written firmware but...

Comment: Ahhhh, okay. That would make sense than. Luckily the company I work for isn't selling these sensors, we only bought one for comparing to the sensor we do sell. Anyway, thank you for explaining things in an easy to understand manner. You were more help than the developers themselves, haha.